# How to append a batch file command line containing redirection operator to a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm creating a batch game of sorts but can't continue until I fix this. When I use `(ECHO type Nul > 10.bat >> 2.bat)` I believe the first `>`  is trying to write the code to `10.bat` which isn't created yet.

Basically I'm trying to have a pick the right file then it progresses to the next level of batch files. I also tried to make the number that it picks between 1 and 10 and the 11 through 19 so on and so fourth random but when I limit `%random%` to a smaller allotment of numbers it doesn't work. Thank you!

```
type NUL > 1.bat
type NUL > 2.bat
type Nul > 3.bat
type Nul > 4.bat
type Nul > 5.bat
type Nul > 6.bat
type Nul > 7.bat
type Nul > 8.bat
type Nul > 9.bat

ECHO del 9.bat >> 1.bat
ECHO del 2.bat >> 1.bat
ECHO del 3.bat >> 1.bat
ECHO del 4.bat >> 1.bat
ECHO del 5.bat >> 1.bat
ECHO del 6.bat >> 1.bat
ECHO del 7.bat >> 1.bat
ECHO del 8.bat >> 1.bat
ECHO del 1.bat >> 1.bat
rem -----------------------
ECHO del 1.bat >> 2.bat
ECHO del 9.bat >> 2.bat
ECHO del 3.bat >> 2.bat
ECHO del 4.bat >> 2.bat
ECHO del 5.bat >> 2.bat
ECHO del 6.bat >> 2.bat
ECHO del 7.bat >> 2.bat
ECHO del 8.bat >> 2.bat
ECHO type Nul > 10.bat >> 2.bat
ECHO type Nul > 11.bat >> 2.bat
ECHO type Nul > 12.bat >> 2.bat
ECHO type Nul > 13.bat >> 2.bat
ECHO type Nul > 14.bat >> 2.bat
ECHO type Nul > 15.bat >> 2.bat
ECHO type Nul > 16.bat >> 2.bat
ECHO type Nul > 17.bat >> 2.bat
ECHO type Nul > 18.bat >> 2.bat
ECHO type Nul > 19.bat >> 2.bat
ECHO del 2.bat >> 2.bat
```

Comment: I know you said it was hard to describe but unfortunately you're going to have to try harder. As you have it, it's unclear what you are asking and your question could be closed.

Comment: I gues you want to echo the first `>` into the output file; if so, you must escape it like `^>`...

Comment: I don't know how to upvote or anything but aschipfl that is just what I was looking for thank you

Answer (score 1):

aschipfl has already shown the solution, but I made a shorter version of your script.

```
for /l %%G in (1,1,9) do (
    type NUL>%%G.bat
)
```

This is bascially the `type NUL>n.bat`

```
for %%G in ("9 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1") do (
    ECHO del %%G.bat >> 1.bat
)
for %%G in ("1 9 3 4 5 6 7 8") do (
    ECHO del %%G.bat >> 2.bat
```

Is the same as your multiple `echo del` statements.

```
for /l %%G in (10,1,19) do (
    ECHO type Nul ^> %%G.bat >> 2.bat
)
```

equals to your `type NUL ^> n.bat >> 2.bat`.